# Removing Duplicates out of List of Np-Arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am working on a project for which I am analyzing and comparing several different binary matrices which represent combinatorial objects. For this, I need to generate and analyze datasets and I have turned to python to do so.
Basically, I have list of np.arrays and I am need to filter out duplicates, i.e. take out all np.arrays which occur more than once. The standard methods do not work (np.arrays are not hashable and normal indexing does not work on them either.)

What I attempted was the following, which also did not produce the desired result:

```
res = [y[i] for i in range(len(y)) if i == y.index(y[i]) ]
```

I receive an error telling me I need the all() or any() function, which kind of eliminates the point of the entire operation. Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this?

Remark: I know there are several questions on this topic with normal lists and I know how to approach these, but using np.arrays make this a lot more difficult..

Comment: The `==` operator on np arrays produces another array with `False` or `True` in each cell.  The `all` function will return `True` if all the elements of that array are `True`.  There is no shortcut to this; the only way to determine equality is to compare each cell.

Comment: @Tim Roberts So I really have to brute-force compare every cell to every other cell to determine obtain my array without multiples?

Comment: Well, you can let numpy do it, but IT has to do an element-by-element comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Works with numpy arrays:
Given

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6].
              [4, 5, 6]])
```

You can do:

```
b = np.unique(a, axis=0)
```

This gives you a numpy array which is the same shape as a, but with all the duplicates removed. So in this example:

```
print(b)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```